# SaltStack: pip install only when git checkout changes

Tags: saltstack

I'm working on a salt state to deploy a python app. It's mostly working. One issue I have is that pip install run every time the salt minion runs. I only want it to run when there is a new commit in the git checkout. I tried a both onchange and watch requirements, but this did not help.

This is my salt state:

```
dmt src:
  git.latest:
    - target: /opt/dmt/src/dmt
    - name: git@gitlab.xyz.co.za:lsd/dmt.git
    - identity: /opt/dmt/src/deploy_id_rsa
    - force: True
    - force_checkout: True
    - force_reset: True
    - require:
      - file: /opt/dmt/src
      - file: /opt/dmt/src/deploy_id_rsa


dmt virtualenv:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - name: /opt/dmt
    - system_site_packages: False
    - use_wheel: True
    - python: /usr/bin/python2

dmt pip install:
  pip.installed:
    - onchange:
      - git: dmt src
    - requires:
      - virtualenv: dmt virtualenv
    - name: ""
    - pip_bin: /opt/dmt/bin/pip
    - editable: /opt/dmt/src/dmt
```

How can I make the `pip install` only run when there is a new commit in the git checkout?

Comment: Hi Gary.  Was this question answered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is plural: "onchange**s**"

```
dmt pip install:
  pip.installed:
    - onchanges:
      - git: "dmt src"
    - requires:
      - virtualenv: "dmt virtualenv"
    {# ...snip... #}
```